# unbind click inside on();

Tags: jquery

I'm having problem unbinding a click event on a specific element. this is my JS code.

```
    $(document).on('click','.likecomment', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var commentid = $(this).data('commentid');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '?category=likecomment',
            data: {
                "commentid" : commentid
            },
            success: function(){
                $(this).unbind('click');
                var likes = $('#'+commentid+'-likes').text();
                likes++;
                $('#'+commentid+'-likes').html(likes);
            }
        });
    return false;
});
```

The functionality of an element persist after one click. How can I prevent it from being clickable after first click? If the code is correct I'll probably figure out the problem myself but I just want to make sure that the code is correct or not.

Comment: why dont you go for [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Comment: Probably because he has more than one `.likecomment` and .one would only allow for one of them to be clicked ever, rather than just one click per.

Comment: @sogeek Personally I don't think this is a good idea since it leaves the user with a button he can click without any effect and without any feedback what is going on.

Comment: @KevinB well, just attach the event handler to the class itself instead. This will simply do the thing. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cEs2g/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're delegating the event to the `document` object, the handler is bound on `document`, not on each individual `.likecomment` element.

You wouldn't want to unbind the event in case there are multiple elements that the delegated event would match, and you probably wouldn't want to remove the `likecomment` class as it would probably be associated with styles.

Instead, use a selector that forces a non-match when another class is added. `done` is being used for this example, although it could be `finished`, `liked`, or some other class name you prefer:

```
$(document).on('click', '.likecomment:not(.done)', function () {...});
```

And when you want to stop the element from causing a click event, add the `done` class to the element:

```
$(this).addClass('done');
```

Adding the new class also provides a hook for changing the styles of `likecomment` so that it no longer looks clickable.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. Seems like the most sophisticated way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Use the matching .off syntax.

```
$(document).off('click','.likecomment');
```

or make the current element no longer match `.likecomment`

```
$(this).removeClass("likecomment");
```

or

```
$(this).removeClass("delegated");
// with this change to binding method:
$(document).on('click','.likecomment.delegated', function(e){
```

However keep in mind that `this` inside of your success call is not the same `this` outside of it, you need to add this ajax option: `context: this,` so that the `this` inside your ajax will be the same as it is outside your ajax.

Comment: Would the off() function not disable all the elements with the class attribute likecomment? So by "simply" adding context : this in the ajax object literal like data{ context : this } would make this work inside the callback function?

Comment: No, because the click event is bound to the document, not the `.likecomment` element. If you want to stop the event from happening to that one element, make that one element not match `.likecomment`

Comment: I'm not fond of the idea of removing `likecomment` as it seems like the sort of class that would be used for styling. It would be better all-around to [update the selector and add a new class](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12976613/497418).

Comment: @zzzzBov Agreed, that's why i didn't exactly say that in the text, i left that up to the developer to decide how he wants to *"make the current element no longer match `.likecomment`"*. I'll add an example of that

Answer (score 1):

This might be because you're unbinding within the success handler. If your ajax call takes a while then your unbind will also take a while. So after your $.ajax try:

```
$(this).prop({disabled: true});
```

Comment: I could have sworn that elements would still fire `click` events when disabled...[and I was very wrong](http://jsfiddle.net/TRCXx/). Sorry about the confusion.